# AspnetBoilerPlate Docker Deployment

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, aspnetboilerplate

I want to containerize `Aspnetboilerplate` project in order to deploy on Digital Ocean. Is there an example `Dockerfile` I can use ?

Comment: The template comes with `Dockerfile`s.

Answer (score 0):

For backend dotnetcore, you can use the dotnet core examples: [dotnetcore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/)